# rails: updating controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am really new to rails and I am just trying to figure this out. I have the following model, where user can be student or teacher.

```
User(Student) belongs_to profile.
Profile belongs_to user.
Profile has_many grades.
Grade belongs_to profile.
Grade belongs_to class.
Class has_many grades.
Class belongs_to User(Teacher).
```

We can ignore the User part for now...

My question is, I want to add points to a users grade and I am not sure what needs to be done in the model/controller/view classes.

For example, I am a teacher and I am on the class's show.html.erb page. I want to make a form where I can specify the user's name and bonus points.

This will create a new grade if it doesn't already exist or add points to an existing grade if it does exist for the specify profile's name.

How should the model/view/controller classes look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not look like you need any new models.

You will need a BonusesController with new and create actions.

new.html.erb will be a simple form using a form_tag which will POST your information to your create action.

Implement the logic of looking up a user, and creating/modifying grades in the BonusesController create action.